# ¿Qué significa el siguiente código de ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Me gustaría saber que realiza el `HtmlDecode` en esta variable de sesión, ¿Cuál es su utilidad?

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Session["_contenido"].ToString());
```

Comment: Pudieras especificar si webforms o razor?

Answer (score 2):

`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` esta funcion se encarga de trransformar tu `string` a html, es decir si tienes un string como `string a = "<b>TEXTO..</b>"` y lo renderizas en tu documento asp como:

```
@a (si lo declaras directamente desde tu vista) o @ViewBag.a
```

tu resultado será tal y como lo escribistes en la variable, es decir se imprime:*`<b>TEXTO..</b>`*

> Con **`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()`**

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(a)
```

tu resultado será: **TEXTO..**

Cuando Usas la función ***Session*** ( `Session['nombreVariable'] = 'valor'` ), esta se encarga que la variable exista en todo tu proyecto y con una sola vez declarada existirá siempre si no hasta que la destruyas con `Session.Clear();`

> **En fín** lo que haces con `HtmlDecode(Session["_contenido"].ToString());` es descodificas una variable (Session) a HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Segun la [documentacion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Convierte una cadena que ha sido codificada en HTML para transmisión
>   HTTP en una cadena decodificada.

En otra palabras, invalida el html que puede tener el string para que no sea renderizado como tal.

Por ejemplo si imprimieras:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    string html = "<strong>Hola mundo</strong>";
}

@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html)
```

El resultado seria:

```
&lt;strong&gt;Hola mundo&lt;/strong&gt;
```

[Ejemplo online.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a9gDx8)